# is precompilation necessary when switching DB2LUW node?

Tags: db2, embedded-sql

Embedded SQL application for DB2LUW is developed in following steps:

1. db2 prep
2. db2 bind

Assume we have 2 DB2LUW nodes and DDL are identical for both nodes. When switching DB2LUW node, is precompilation for new node necessary? Or is it possible to start from binding by using the bind file generated when precompiled for the first node?

I mean is it possible to bind in the following way?

[for node1]
1. db2 prep
2. db2 bind

[for node2]
db2 bind by using bind file generated at step1 for node1?

Any comments are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean by node Db2 in MPP cluster? Is it the same database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to use clearer terminology when asking for help.

If by 'node1' and 'node2' you mean *different copies of the same database, possibly with different data, but the same DDL* then you do not need to precompile again, you can simply bind using the previously generated bindfiles.   This assumes both databases use the same platform of Db2.  This is common when promoting embedded-SQL code between environments (development, various-testing, pre-production, production etc.). Any external routines need their deployables promoted appropriately. Always ensure that runstats are appropriate before you bind.

If your 'node1' and 'node2' are part of a High-Availability solution (either active:passive on failover/failback, or primary:standby after takeovers, or purescale-members), then it is the same database so you don't need to rebind. You can rebind if you want to - but not essential.

Comment: Thank you Mao. Now I am clear. What I meant was "different copies of the same database, possibly with different data, but the same DDL". So pre-compilation is not necessary. Only bind is needed. Thank you!